# Addition of Number Elements from a List in Terraform

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to add every number with the next one from a list and then the result to be added to the next number from the same list?

For example:

```
[0, 2, 5, 9]
```

Is there a way to get:

```
[0, 2, 7, 16]
```

I've come to:

```
resource "null_resource" "dmns_calc_l" {
  count = "${length(local.num_cntd_and_zero_l) - 1}"

  triggers {
    num_calc_l = "${local.num_cntd_and_zero_l[count.index] + local.num_cntd_and_zero_l[count.index + 1]}"
  }
}

locals {
  num_calc_and_zero_l = [
    "${0}",
    "${null_resource.dmns_calc_l.*.triggers.num_calc_l}",
  ]
}
```

However, as it is clearly to see it - it is good enough only for a list of 3 elements /and if the first element is "0"/ because it does NOT add up with the previous addition result.

Comment: Might this be a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)? Maybe you can describe what you are trying to achive in the end and we can figure out a way to reach it without this calculation?

Comment: I need to slice dynamically from a list of strings in another resource - so that I can build properly the "validation_record_fqdns" /part of the resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation"/. I have a list with all the FQDN's and I need to select a range from it - let's say from position "0" to "3" and then from "4" to "5".

Comment: I propose for you to update the question to reflect your overall goal and use the question above an example what you tried so far. This way, the question might get more attention from experts having solved a similar problem in another way.

Comment: @Markus - thanks for your time, Markus - it's appreciated :-)